# php continue skips the condition evaluation

Tags: php

In my simple code 'continue' skips the condition evaluation and jumps straight to beginning of loop body (the if line) causing infinite loop. I can see that's exactly what happens when debugging and resuming execution with breakpoint on loop condition (it doesn't break) or when using step over. Probably just me being tired but I'm clueless.

```
while ( ($line = _e(fgets($dump_file))) !== FALSE )
{
    if ($line === '')
    {
        echo 'continue';
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: thats the normal behavior, continue will proceed to next iteration

Comment: Maybe you wanted the `break` keyworkd ;)

Comment: And keep in mind you can always break as many levels as you want. So if you have nested loops use `break 3` or whatever the level you want to break to.

Comment: What does the function _`_e`_ do? Will it ever pass on the 'end of file' (`FALSE`) returned by `fgets`? Also, your code is incomplete - what happens after the supplied `if` statement? i.e. what does the code do if there are no empty lines in the file, Should the _`_e`_ function be used inside the loop rather than in the _`while`_ test? imo, the 'continue' test is working fine and the issue is with the `while` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the result of _e to $line in your while loop. I'm assuming you're getting _e from WordPress, which is documented here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e .

> Return Values
>
> (void)
>
> This function does not return a value.

So, your loop basically says:

```
while (void !== False) {
    continue;
}
```

Which, of course, continues forever.

Note that several answers have stated that the `break` statement should have been used. The code above is designed to abort the loop when the end of file (EOF) is hit, to which [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) returns `False`. Each time the loop is run, `fgets` reads the next line until it reaches the end of the file, at which point it returns `False`.

From php.net:

> Returns a string of up to length - 1 bytes read from the file pointed to by handle. If there is no more data to read in the file pointer, then FALSE is returned.

The problem here isn't that a `break` statement is needed, because the while condition will be false when `fgets` returns `False`. The issue is that _e returns `void` which `!== False` and therefore the loop continues indefinitely.

Quick solution is to remove the _e in the `while` statement and apply it to the string later in your code block if necessary.

Comment: Nope, sorry for confusion. Not using wordpress here, just my own code. The _e function evaluates the string and removes some unwanted characters. Also my problem is not that while loop condition is being evaluated to value other then expected. The problem is that the while condition does not get evaluated at all - as stated.

Comment: OK you're onto something here after all. As suggested by Ryan Vincent my string processing function _e does not account for argument being FALSE value so that's probably that. I still don't see why debugger would not break on the condition. Let me fix _e function before I confirm the problem solved.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to break on the while itself. I'm not sure which debugger you're using, but most debuggers won't ever stop on the while loop. Load up a quick piece of sample code that has a very simple while condition and try to break there in your debugger. My guess is you have to break on the first line of the block inside the while.

You're right, you definitely need _e to return False when fgets does.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean but I'm pretty sure I would use breakpoints on loop conditions all the time with success. Can't really test now cause the debugger is totally acting out. I'm using PHPStorm - WAMP/XDEBUG. Thanks for all the help. Exact explanation of what happend in my own reply.

Comment: My mistake. After execution is inside the loop the debugger doesn't break on or step through loop line in this setup either. Must have got confused by another environment - VS+C# which I was using today also.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `break` keyword to stop a loop.

Continue will go to the beginning of the next loop iteration while skipping the rest of your loop.

More info :

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: You're right, the problem he is facing might be because of the _e() method not retuning the FALSE

Answer (score 2):

`continue` will always continue to the next iteration of the loop.

The loop is infinite because the value of `$line` never changes within the loop, so either the loop infinitely executes or never does at all depending on the initial value of `$line`.

`break` will break out of the loop

Comment: The value of $line actually change in the conditionnal expression while(($line =...

Answer (score 1):

OK so here's what happened. Problem with the infinite loop was indeed due to my _e function not accounting for it's argument being FALSE value and always returning a string so the while loop condition would always evaluate to TRUE as suggested by Ryan Vincent and geis.

However that does not explain why my debugger would not break on the condition. Turns out that this problem is not related. The debugger it self is acting out and now refusing to break on all kinds of random breakpoints for no good reason.

Marking geis's answer as solution for all the effort.